# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'branch')

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

I'm creating a dashboard of an application in Angular and whenever I try to access this dashboard, it's giving an error :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'branch')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'branch')

The method in the Service looks like this:

```
getUserData() {
    let users = window.localStorage.getItem('users');
    let jsonUsers = JSON.parse(users!) 
    console.log("data: ", JSON.parse(jsonUsers.branch.id));

    return jsonUsers.branch.id;
}
```

My interfaces:

```typescript
export interface Users { 
  id: string; 
  firstName: string; 
  lastName: string; 
  email: string; 
  username: string; 
  branch: Branch[]; 
  roles: string; 
  securityGroups: string; 
}


export interface Branch { 
  company: Company[]; 
  id: string; 
  name: string; 
}
```

What could be happening? Sorry if I'm missing more things to put in doubt, anything I'll add if needed. I tried a few things but none worked.

Comment: You get an error because `jsonUsers.branch` is `null`. Are you sure there is something named "users" in your local storage and that it contains what you're trying to manipulate ?

Comment: @Lauromine no `jsonUsers` is `null`. As the error says, it cannot read the property `branch` of `null`. If `jsonUsers.branch` was null, then it wouldn't be able to read the property `id` of `null`.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh yes, sorry !

Comment: You have more than one problem there. You're not checking if users exists after reading it. But also you're not casting to get type checking: `let jsonUsers: Users | null = JSON.parse(users);` Because of this you're making other mistakes like reading `branch.id` when branch is an array not a regular object.

Answer (score 0):

With the `user!` you are telling to the ts compiler that `user` is not `null` so the compiler exclude the option that the user can be `null`, but the function `window.location.getItem` return `string` or `null` so the code should be someting like this:

```js
getUserData() {
    const users = window.localStorage.getItem('users');
    if (user === null){
       console.error("key 'users' in local storage is 'null'");
       throw new Error("User is not in storage");
    }
    const jsonUsers = JSON.parse(users) 
    console.log("data: ", JSON.parse(jsonUsers.branch.id));

    return jsonUsers.branch.id;
}
```

The problem is that `window.localStorage.getItem('users')` return `null`